# Typescript - how to only compile from one folder

Tags: typescript

I have a folder structure similar to this (numbers to show depth):

```
1. project/
  2. package/
    3. dist/
    3. src/
      4. index.tsx
    3. tsconfig.json
1. test1/
  2. file1.tsx
1. test2/
  2. file2.tsx
```

Inside `project/package/src/index.tsx`, I import the test files like so:

```
import TestFile1 from "../../../test1/file1"
import TestFile2 from "../../../test2/file2"
```

The reason for this is because I'm creating an npm package and I want to be able to import config files from the project root (i.e. instead of `root/project/package/dist` the folder structure will become `root/node_modules/packagescope/package`, and I want to import `test1/file1` and `test2/file2` from the `root` directory).

During development of the package I have some test files I use as a temporary replacement, but I don't want these to be added to the `dist` folder on compile. I want to be able to type-check these files to ensure there are no errors, but I don't want them compiled. I basically want an "excludes" option that applies to **compile only**.

What I **want** to happen is when I run `tsc`, it compiles the files in `project/package/src` and outputs it to `project/package/dist`. So after compiling, I should have the file `project/package/dist/index.js`.

The issue I have is that if I set the rootDir to the `project/package/src` folder, I get the error:

```
error TS6059: File 'C:/.../test1/file1.tsx' is not under 'rootDir' 
'C:/.../project/package/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

> it compiles the files in project/package/src and outputs it to project/package/dist. So after compiling, I should have the file project/package/dist/index.js

You will have to put all src in `src`. Move the `test` into `src` and then `.npmignore` `dist/test`.

## Example

TypeStyle is an open source example : https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle/tree/master/src/tests

Comment: I can't put it all in project/package/src though as that would break my imports. They need to be located where they are. I also don't want them compiled into project/package/dist as they are for testing during development only. They aren't distribution files.

Comment: `They aren't distribution files.` They will not be distributed if you add them to ignore files. `I can't put it all in project/package/src though as that would break my imports` If you don't change your imports TypeScript will have to make the folder structure match. So if you want the output folder structure of `src` -> `dist` you have to match the input aka put all files in `src` 

Comment: The imports can't be changed. Those files cannot be added to the src folder. Thanks for your help but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question.